# Search for location.hash inside block

Tags: javascript, jquery, location

We are on the page `http://site.com/movies/#posters`

```
<div class="content">
    <div id="posters"></div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to use this code, for jump to block with id `posters` and add class `active` to it:

```
$(location.hash).addClass("active");
```

It works good, **but has a problem**. If there is a link like `<a href="http://site.com/movies/actuale/#posters">Actuale</a>`, it jumps to this link, not to `<div id="posters"></div>`

Should jump to block with `id="posters` inside `class="content"` block.

`<div id="posters"></div>` should become `<div class="active" id="posters"></div>`

**How to do that?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to scroll to the element and prevent the link from firing.

Make a function to do this:

```
function ScrollToHash() {
    var posX = 0, posY = 0;
    var obj = document.getElementById(document.location.hash);
    while(obj) {
        posY += obj.offetTop;
        posX += obj.offsetLeft;
        obj = obj.offsetParent;
    }
    window.scrollTo(posX, posY);
}
```

You'd also have to add an onclick handler to your link:

```
<a href="#posters" onclick="ScrollToHash(); return false;">Link</a>
```

The only problem is that `document.location.hash` gives you the `hash` value of the current page, not of the link.  You'd have to find a different way to do that.

I may be misinterpreting what you're attempting to do, so hopefully this at least points you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Happy, I think you must be using duplicate IDs.  `$('#posters')` will select an element with `id="posters"`, not a link that simply contains `#posters` is the `href` attribute.  I suggest you look at your HTML and make sure that the link isn't actually ID'd `posters` as well.